# Why the accuracy is high but the result for confusion matrix is bad?

Tags: python, prediction, confusion-matrix, k-fold

I have trained a vgg16 model with a total of 1000 images for 5 classes (200 images for each class). I have used data augmentation, stratified K-fold, and dropout to train the model. The train accuracy and val accuracy is good. However, when i do prediction on the trained model with test dataset, the result of confusion matrix is not compatible with the train accuracy.

[Train & Val accuracy[Classification report[Confusion Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMr5d.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIX3O.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAPXC.png)

VGG model:

```
def create_model():
  # (CNN) is a multilayered neural network with a special architecture to detect complex features in data.
  # VGG16 = Visual Geometry Group 
  # 16 = 16 refers to it has 16 layers that have weights
  # VGG16 have 128 million parameters
  # 3x3 filter with stride 1 
  # maxpool layer of 2x2 filter of stride 2
  # Conv-1 Layer has 64 number of filters 
  # Conv-2 has 128 filters
  # Conv-3 has 256 filters
  # Conv 4 and Conv 5 has 512 filters

  # import library 
  from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
  from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
  from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Conv2D

  # number of species
  NO_CLASSES = 5
  # load the VGG16 model as the base model for training
  # exclude the fully connected layer
  base_model = VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
  # add layers
  x = base_model.output
  x = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu')(x) # output layer will be 64x64, (3x3) kernel
  x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x) # use average pooling as we dont have min pooling which selects the darkest pixels from image (our dataset here is white background) 
  # add dense layers so that the model can learn more complex functions and classify for netter results
  # Dense layer = a layer that is deeply connected with its preceding layer
  x = Flatten()(x) # for feeding into fully connected layer as fully connected layer only accept 1D
  x = Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x)                                
  x = Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x)       # dense layer 2
  x = Dense(512,activation='relu')(x)        # dense layer 3
  x = Dropout(0.2)(x) # reduce dependency between neurons


  # final layer with softmax activation for multiclass classification
  preds = Dense(NO_CLASSES, activation='softmax')(x) 

  # layers of the VGG16 model are frozen, bcuz we dont want their weights to changes during model training
  # create a new model with the base model's original input and the new model's output
  model = Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = preds)
  # don't train the first 19 layers - 0..18
  for layer in model.layers[:19]:
      layer.trainable=False
  # train the rest of the layers - 19 onwards
  for layer in model.layers[19:]:
      layer.trainable=True
          
  # compile the model  
  model.compile(optimizer='Adam', # Adam optimizer -- training cost (low) and performance (high)
            loss='categorical_crossentropy', # for multi-class(classes are mutually exclusive) problem
            metrics=['accuracy']) # calculate accuracy
  return model
```

Stratified K fold & model fit

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from statistics import mean, stdev
EPOCHS = 6
histories = []

kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle=True, random_state=123)

for f, (trn_ind, val_ind) in enumerate(kfold.split(train_dataset.Image_path, train_dataset.labels)):
  print(); print("#"*50)
  print("Fold: ",f+1)
  print("#"*50)
  train_ds = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(train_dataset.loc[trn_ind,:], 
                                         x_col='Image_path', y_col='labels',
                                         target_size=(width,height),
                                         class_mode = 'categorical', color_mode = 'rgb',
                                         batch_size = 16, shuffle = True)
  val_ds = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(train_dataset.loc[val_ind,:], 
                                       x_col='Image_path', y_col='labels',
                                       target_size=(width,height),
                                       class_mode = 'categorical', color_mode = 'rgb',
                                       batch_size = 16, shuffle = True)

  
  # Define start and end epoch for each folds
  fold_start_epoch = f * EPOCHS
  fold_end_epoch = EPOCHS * (f+1)

  step_size_train = train_ds.n // train_ds.batch_size
  # fit
  history=model.fit(train_ds, 
                    initial_epoch=fold_start_epoch , 
                    epochs=fold_end_epoch, 
                    validation_data=val_ds, 
                    shuffle=True, 
                    steps_per_epoch=step_size_train,
                    verbose=1)
  
  
  # store history for each folds
  histories.append(history)
```

Does this happened is because of the dataset itself or the coding problem? I hope to find the mistake.